# Owner & Group setting for OpenCart install on CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos, permissions, apache-httpd

I'm setting up a development server on a HP microserver with CentOS 6.3. I'm relatively new to Linux and have ran into some issues/confusion. I have the server fully setup/updated with yum. It's a headless server & I'm connecting via PuTTY. For the following installs of OpenCart, I'm logged in via SSH as a regular non-root user.

I'm trying to do a clean install of OpenCart 1.5.4.1. I tried setting OC up with Yum first and came up against permission/ownership issues, so I forgot about doing it that way. Then I just extracted the files locally on my windows machine and FTP'ed them into my required directory. I was still getting folder unwritable errors when trying to install OC. I set the req'd folders to their recommended permissions (755) and temporarily turned off SELinux. It still wouldn't allow me to install, I was still getting the folder unwritable errors. I eventually changed the owner of these directories to Apache and this seemed to allow it to install.

Is this correct? Can anyone help me with what the group and owner should be set to? I know it's only a dev server but I want to try and simulate a live server and have it as secure as possible and learn to do things the correct way. Even a link to a page/tutorial that would point me in the right direction would be great.

I've trawled the web & posted a Q on the OpenCart forums but got no reply. As I'm quite new to the Linux world my knowledge is limited & I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Think I may well find the answer in one of these two answers:
http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-are-the-best-linux-permissions-to-use-for-my-website
http://serverfault.com/questions/212269/tips-for-securing-a-lamp-server
I'll give them a proper read tomorrow morning.